# No Milestone Icon for Kendo Summary Task

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

I am developing a gantt chart using Telerik's Kendo UI for JQuery. I am using the Material css theme. If I add a Summary Task with a single Milestone Task within it, the Milestone Task displays as a diamond but the parent Summary Task is a Task of zero length which cannot be seen:

[image: Milestone Summary Task appears invisible]

I have seen examples where a smaller diamond is depicted for the Summary Task. I checked the dates for the Summary Task and the Start and End are identical. Am I missing something here please?

Comment: Can you please link the examples you mentioned?

Comment: https://dojo.telerik.com/UVuVAcoG It may be somehow linked to the styling.